# ListView, CheckBoxes and the ID's

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

So, i'm having a problem (newbie one) with a CheckBox Listener AND a ListView. I need to request the '...long id) that passes through the Overriden method onListItemClick and put it into a OnCheckedChangeListener. How should i do that?

If you guys need the code i can post it!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hey man, i'm still having some problems. I cant get it done :(
Could you give some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using checkboxes in ListView but ListView's choiceMode instead. It takes care of everything for you.

If you really want to keep using checkboxes, you could store the id of your item in the tag of your checkbox in the Adapter's getView() (or bindView()) method. Look at View.setTag() to see how to do this.